# How to remove variables that are highly correlated in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am having a dataset where 57 variables are there out of which a few variables are highly correlated with other variables(corr=1). Is there any procedure available in SAS in which highly correlated variables can be dropped from the correlation matrix?

Comment: Are all variables the same type - numeric, ordinal, categorical?

Comment: Are you concerned only about high correlation to another variable or about linear combinations.  IE v10 = 1 + 5*v8 - 2*v13?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude those variables from the model. For example:

```
proc glm data=have;
     model y = x1 x2 x3;
run;
```

If x1 and x2 are highly correlated, drop one from the model:

```
proc glm data=have;
     model y = x1 x3;
run;
```

If you have a lot of variables that would be too tedious to type out, you can drop them directly from the dataset using the `drop=` option:

```
proc glm data=have(drop=x2 x32 x49);
    model y = x1--x57;
run;
```

`--` selects all variables between and including `x1` and `x57`, with `x2`, `x32`, and `x49` dropped from the dataset that `proc glm` is reading.

If you have a more complicated model that includes both class variables and numeric variables, you can combine the SAS column dictionary table and macro language to store exactly what you need.

The below code will obtain all character and numeric variables from your dataset, which we are assuming is called `have` and stored in a library called `LIBREF`. We are filtering out the correlated variables that we do not want to include. Note that in the 2nd query, we filter out `y`. We always want to filter out the `y` variable here, otherwise we will be creating a model that says `y = itself + other factors`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into :classvars separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = 'LIBREF'
          AND memname = 'HAVE'
          AND type = 'num'
          AND name NOT IN('x3', 'x4')
   ;

   select name
   into :numvars separated by ' '
   from sashelp.vcolumn
   where libname = 'LIBREF'
         AND memname = 'HAVE'
         AND type = 'num'
         AND name NOT IN('y', 'x1', 'x6')
   ;
quit;
```

You will find that the macro variables `&numvars` and `&classvars` store the needed values. Now you don't need to type them all out! You can check this by running the below and looking in the log:

```
%put CLASS VARIABLES: &classvars;
%put NUMERIC VARIABLES: &numvars;
```

You can then run `proc glm` using these macro variables to represent only the variables that you want to model:

```
proc glm data=have;
    class &classvars;
    model y = &classvars &numvars;
run;
```